# Contract to check if sum of uint8 exceeds type(uint8).max

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

Hi I am a bit of a newbie in solidity, for a school exercise I need to compute the following contract:

```
contract mySolution {
function sum(uint8 x, uint8 y) external pure returns (bool, uint8) {
// checks if the sum of x and y exceeds type(uint8).max
// if so, returns the bool as false, and the uint8 as zero
// if not, returns the bool as true, and the uint8 as the sum x+y.
}
```

I attempted it and got the following:

```
contract mySolution {
function sum(uint8 x, uint8 y) external pure returns (bool, uint8) {
  uint8 z = x + y; 
  if (z > type(uint8).max) {
      return(false,0);
  }  else {
      return(true,z);
  } 

}
```

Could you give me any pointers to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What pragma version is your teacher asking to be used?
Also, this can not work because for pragma > 0.8, if x + y is > 255, the line uint8 z = x + y will revert, and for pragma < 0.8, it will overflow silently

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, but please understand why this works and read my comment i left on your post. You won't learn anything by me feeding you the answer so please follow up with question until you fully understand the answer

```
 function sum(uint8 x, uint8 y) external pure returns (bool, uint8) {
        if (type(uint8).max - x < y) {
            return(false,0);
        }  else {
            return(true, x + y);
        } 
    }
```